# PCRE how to match match multiple occurrences with multiple options?

Tags: regex, pcre

I would like create a pattern that will match

```
"foo | bar"
"baz | foo"
"foo & bar"
"baz ; bar"
```

That is, the "keywords" are "foo", "bar" and "baz".

At least 2 of them shall appear.

Their order does not matter.

They shall have either ";", "&" or "|" in between.

Is there an expression I can create to match this?

I am not looking for a "hard-coded" one, such as

```
(foo|bar|baz)[\|&;](foo|bar|baz)
```

Rather a way to do this more "generic", as the list of keywords is actually far larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like:

```
^(?=\w)((^|[\|&;])(foo|bar|baz|...other.keywords...)){2,}"
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Comment: what's the role of `(?=\w)` ?

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay: It ensures that the string starts with a keyword and not an operator. (Without it, the pattern would accept something like `"&foo&bar"`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your "hard-coded" solution is as close to this as regular expressions will get on their own, but assuming this is within some scripting environment, you could combine a more generic regex with some procedural code.

For instance, you could capture any two words with a pattern like `/([a-z])[/|&;]([a-z])/` and then check the words found against a list or hash table to see if you have a correct match.